# using smart table in express template engine ejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using smart table in express template engine ejs. But I don't know how to get table data values at the time of editing table data.

I am using PUT method for updating the smart table data with the help of method-overriding. Without method-overriding PUT and DELETE are showing page not found error. I am unable to get updated data with PUT method from smart table.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.put('/edit/(:id)', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("edit data : ", req.body, req.params);
var device = { id: req.params.id }

req.getConnection(function (error, conn) {
  conn.query('UPDATE users SET ? WHERE id = ' + req.params.id, device, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect('/liveDevices')
    } else {
      res.redirect('/liveDevices')
    }
  })
})
})
```

```
         <% liveDevices.forEach((data, i) => { %>
<tr>
  <td name="sno"><%= ++i %></td>
  <td><input class="no-edit" type="text" value=<%= data.device_id %> disabled /></td>
  <td><input class="no-edit" type="text" value=<%= data.deviceTopic %> disabled /></td>
  <td><span class="edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil mr-4" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <form method='POST' action='/liveDevices/edit/<%= data.device_id %>?_method=PUT'><button type="submit"><i
            class="fa fa-check off mr-4" aria-hidden="true"></button></i></form>
    </span><span><a href="/liveDevices/remove/<%= data.device_id %>"><i class="fa fa-trash"
          aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span></td>
</tr>
<% }) %>
```

Actual output : edit data :  {} { id: '9' }

Expected output : edit data : {If i click on edit button of smart table whose id=9 so it gives whole updated data values here in this block} {id : '9'}

Comment: you're not PUTing any data/fields so body will be empty

Comment: also `/liveDevices/remove/<%= data.device_id %>` is a GET why whould it hit delete() endpoint?

Comment: also `UPDATE users SET ? WHERE id = ' + req.params.id` wont work (binding to columns and is open to SQL injection)

Comment: After putting data in both two input fields like name="device_id" and name="device_topic" respectively. but output is same, not getting any data in req.body.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone